# gstreamer : don't see an element related to vp9 parser

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I see that in https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-bad/tree/1.10/gst-libs/gst/codecparsers, there is gstvp9parser.c . But when I compile gstreamer bad plugins, I don't see an element related to vp9 parser. Has anybody been able to figure out how to use the vp9 parser?

TIA